# What to do if nodeValue contains only a space and nothing more

Tags: php, html, dom

Let's assume I need to copy this HTML into a variable (server-side, thus PHP):

```
<text>
  <i>The text
    <inserted> </inserted>
    <inserted>has changed</inserted>
  </i>
</text>
```

So I use this kind of code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); # HTML from above
foreach ($x->query("//text") as $node) 
{
    $the_html .= $node->C14N()
}
```

([`DOMNode::C14N()`](http://www.php.net/domnode.c14n) is a super find for me)

So, everything is fine, except that the result is like this:

```
 <text>
  <i>The text
    <inserted></inserted>
    <inserted>has changed</inserted>
  </i>
</text>
```

The space inside first *`<inserted>`* is gone! Debugging like this:

```
echo 'damn' . $node->firstChild->firstChild->nodeValue . 'it';
```

also returns 'damnit'.

Is there a way to preserve the space? (I tried with [`DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace`](http://php.net/class.domdocument#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) but it is not the solution apparently.)

Or is it impossible, and I should change my approach?

Comment: Check [this comment on the DOMNode::C14N documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php#111773), the user recommends using saveHTML when working with malformed HTML, see if that example works in your case.

Comment: Thank you Rolando, this works exactly as C14N (which I wasn't aware of) but the result is still the same, no space..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that:

- You used `loadHTML()` to load this chunk.
- [HTML rules of Whitespace](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) did correctly apply and technically the space "was never there". It is technically not possible to encode a space at that place with an undefine tag named `<inserted>` there. This would require for example `<pre>`.
- Using `loadXML()` instead preserves the whitespace.

---

> Let's assume I need to copy this HTML into a variable (server-side, thus PHP):

Okay, let's do that:

```
$html = '<text>
  <i>The text
    <inserted> </inserted>
    <inserted>has changed</inserted>
  </i>
</text>';
```

> So I use this kind of code: [...] So, everything is fine, [sic!] except that the result is like this: [...]

```
foreach($xpath->query("//text") as $node) {
    echo $node->C14N();
}
```

Gives *exactly* this:

```
<text>
  <i>The text
    <inserted> </inserted>
    <inserted>has changed</inserted>
  </i>
</text>
```

Your question therefore asks about a problem that does not exists. You miss to specify a concrete problem and provide a self-contained code-example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry if I could not state my problem clearly. What I need is to copy a node, and all its children, into a variable in PHP. My problem is that if a node contains only a space, then that space is ignored. I constantly fail to get the result that you say it will give. The example of my problem can be seen at http://ideone.com/ftCO6f. Can you please show me how do you manage to preserve that space?

Comment: I'm not so sure if you really state a problem here at all. According to the link you've given in your last comment you're making use of the `loadHTML()` method which implies you want to have your input treat as HTML. The `<inserted>` tag is not part of HTML and also [in HTML rules of whitespace normalization apply](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html). This space is *perfectly fine to be dropped*. In fact *it does not exist* (you can not express it with HTML that way). If you need it, wrap it into `<pre>` for example. Or use `loadXML()` (as I did in my example).

Comment: Thank you hakre, and you're right, my bad. I used loadHTML instead of loadXML, hence my problem, so there really was no problem, just my lack of understanding it. I vote to delete.

Comment: Well, we can keep it for further reference as this is now fully outlined. I was not so sure if your mistake was to use loadHTML instead of loadXML or you were asking about HTML here. Just keep in mind for next time: If we have a question, we also question our own (mis-) conception of things. In programming questions one way we can reduce this a little is to find technical reference to relate to. Your question does not do that (for the Spaces in HTML part), however, it's now here in the comments, so I say it's fine. I just did a pretty verbose answer to show you where  I saw the lack of specs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all whitespace is ignored in XML, regardless of preserveWhiteSpace flag, so

```
<inserted> </inserted>
```

will always be NULL.
The only solution I've seen (at [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/919863-read-xml-nodevalue-when-conatins-all-character-white-space)) is to mark this as character data:

```
<inserted><![CDATA[ ]]></inserted>
```

And to do it in a matter similar to this:

```
foreach($x->query("//text") as $node) {
  if ($node->nodeValue == '') {
    $cdata = $node->ownerDocument->createCDATASection(' ');
    $node->appendChild($cdata);
  } else {
    foreach($node->childNodes as $node) {
      if ($node->nodeValue == '') {
        $cdata = $node->ownerDocument->createCDATASection(' ');
        $node->appendChild($cdata);
    }
  }
}
```